# Listing numbers $1$ to $10$ such that only one number is smaller than its neighbours

Tags: combinatorics

We want to list the numbers $1$ to $10$ such that the list starts with $1$ and ends with $10$ in a way that only one of the numbers is smaller than both of its neighbours. I want to count the number of ways we can do this.

I tried starting from the rightmost number (before $10$) and counting the possibilities from there. (Fixing where the number that's smaller than its neighbours stands.) I couldn't come up with anything useful though.

Hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the leftmost and rightmost number treated? Do they satisfy the condition automatically, or does their non-existent neighbour default to either "generally larger" or "generally smaller" than the respective boundary number?

Comment: Does $3,4,6,2,5,7,10,9,8,2$ count as a possibility?

Comment: @Henry you are missing $1$ (probably one of your two $2$'s) and it should start with $1$ and end with $10$ so I suppose not

Comment: @LegNaiB so presumably $1,2,5,8,7,4,3,6,9,10$ is OK

Comment: @NerdOnTour I think the problem's statement only refers to the numbers $2, \dots, 9$ so $1$ and $10$ can never have 2 larger neighbours. (I hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: @Henry Yeah, only 3 is smaller than both neighbours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence increases, decreases and increases.
Let the local max be $a$ and the local min is $b$.  Numbers from $a+1,...,10$ line up at the end, and $1,2...,b-1$ line up at the start.
The remaining $a-b-1$ numbers each sit in one of the three intervals, in $3^{a-b-1}$ ways.
Now try to find the sum for all $a$ and $b$

Comment: To explain more, this is to find $\sum_{a=3}^{10}\sum_{b=2}^{a-1} 3^{a-b-1}$, which equals to $1636$ (agrees with @AxelKemper's answer).

Comment: @GarethMa That looks like $\frac14(3^{n-2}-2n+3)$ where $n=10$.  Note that it excludes the case $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ where no inner number is smaller than its two neighbours and requires $n\ge2$ in general

Answer (score 2):

I get $1636$ solutions using the following [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) model:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 10;
set of int: N = 1..n;
array[N] of var N: x;

constraint x[1] == 1;

constraint x[n] == n;

constraint all_different(x);

constraint sum([ (x[i] < x[i-1]) /\ (x[i] < x[i+1])| i in 2..n-1]) == 1;
```

Example solutions:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 10];
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 10];
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 4, 10];
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 5, 10];
x = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 2, 10];
x = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 3, 10];
```

Comment: The problem requires that the first number is $1$ and that the last number is $10$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for a mathematical solution. And N. F. Taussig already mentioned but the list needs to start with 1 and end with 10.